# VB: Object method that prints all its fields

Tags: vb.net, methods

My goal is write a *print to console method* for an object. The method does not require a parameter, but uses nonetheless that object. Calling it would look like:

```
Dim oBHKW As cBHKW
oBHKW.print()
```

But in the cBHKW class, how can I use the oBHKW object?
I tried the following without success.

```
Public Sub print(ByVal sender As Object)
Console.WriteLine(sender.ToString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Me Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e58sbke%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The Me keyword provides a way to refer to the specific instance of a
>   class or structure in which the code is currently executing.

So something like

```
Public Sub print() 
Console.WriteLine(Me.ToString) 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Use extension methods

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module ObjectExtensions
  <Extension()>
  Public Sub Print(sender As Object)
    Console.WriteLine(sender.ToString())
  End Sub
End Module
Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim obj As New TestObject()
    obj.Print()
  End Sub

End Module
Public Class TestObject

End Class
```

Any object you have now you can call "Print()" on and it will send the object itself to the method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx